# disable back button in browser only in specialy page

Tags: asp.net, browser, webforms, postback

I want to disable browser's back button in special page in my site.
how to disable back button only this page.
But when I am pressing Back button of browser,it will redirect me to that secure page from which I've already log out.
Please Give me any solution about this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must disable the cache functionality for our session pages. So for this you have to insert this code into “Page_Load” event of the session page or to master page that is used for secure pages.

This code just disable the cache for current page and save this page in buffer.

```
Response.Buffer= true;
Response.ExpiresAbsolute=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Expires =-1500;
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
if(Session["SessionId"] == null)
{
Response.Redirect ("WhereYouWantToGo.aspx");
}
}
```